# Android Studio loses code order after Git commit

Tags: android, git, commit

My first question on StackOverflow... :-).
I use Android Studio 3.5.2 (Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832, built on October 30, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64, JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.1).
I have few big Java classes (repositories with many dao's). Becouse classes have a lot of code I divide it by lines of comments like this "//----------------------------------------------".
I noticed that after each Git commit (straight from Android Studio) those classes loses order of methods...
For example:
Rows 168-178 before commit:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
// Family (2019-11-21 08:58 OK)

private FamilyDao familyDao = AppHandle.getHandle().getLocalDatabase().familyDao();
private Data<Family> families = new Data<>( familyDao );

public void insertFamily(Family family, MutableLiveData<Long> result ) {
    families.insertData( family, result );
}

public void inserFamilies( ArrayList<Family> familiesList, ProgressPresenter progressPresenter ) {
```

Rows 168-178 after commit:

```
public void findCompetitorPriceById( int id, MutableLiveData<List<CompetitorPrice>> result ) {
    competitorPrices.findDataById( id, result );
}

public void insertFamily(Family family, MutableLiveData<Long> result ) {
    families.insertData( family, result );
}

public void inserFamilies( ArrayList<Family> familiesList, ProgressPresenter progressPresenter ) {
    families.insertDataList( familiesList, progressPresenter );
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thank you for any help.
Regards,

Comment: When committing, you have a couple of checkboxes on the right. Try unselecting Rearrange code and/or Reformat code.

Comment: Yes, "Rearrange code" it is! Thank you very much! You save much my time :-)